# Error Creating Anaconda Custom Environment

Tags: pip, miniconda

I'm using a .yml file to create an environment on an external drive.

My .yml file contains...

```
name: pdal-env

channels:
 — conda-forge

dependencies: 
  - --index-url https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pdal
```

Everything seem to go well - the environment is created...

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

However, I get an error...

```
Installing pip dependencies: \ Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['E:\\E\\PDAL\\env\\pdal-env\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', 'E:\\PDAL\\condaenv.8j8loxa1.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:

Pip subprocess error:
The input line is too long.

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

Is this an error I can just ignore, or do I need to fix it?
If so, how do I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, after receiving a more coherent error message...

```
Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a
nother-project-requirements.txt'

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

My text file was named 'requirements.txt'.
Apparently it must be named 'another-project-requirements.txt'.

Success with no errors.